# Displaying layout marks in a document set with different layouts

Tags: margins, geometry

Is there any package that allows for the display of layout marks within a document where the layout changes several times throughout? I'm using the `geometry` facilities to issuing `\newgeometry` commands throughout my document, but it doesn't update the displayed layout and neither does the `showframe` package or the facilities of the `memoir` class.

EDIT: As Werner has pointed out, the `showframe` option of the `geometry` package displays correctly any updated page layout set by issuing `\newgeometry` commands.

My trouble came out of the fact that I'm issuing also `\pagecolor` commands and the page color seems to be hiding the layout lines typeset according to the `geometry` package. My confusion only worsened because the `showframe` package layout lines were not hidden by the page color (the package got the layout wrong on some pages, though). So, it all boils down to a conflict with the page color.

Even though I'm using `geometry`'s `showframe` option for "debugging" ends, and I don't mind to have no page color at that stage of development, is it possible to override this problem and have at the same time both the page layout displayed by `geometry` as well as the page colored?

Btw, should I open a new question given that the problem is actually different from the originally posted one?

Comment: Do you want crop marks? http://www.ctan.org/pkg/crop

Comment: @Sigur: It's not crop marks that I'm interested in, but the different layout areas, such as textblock, header and footer, and margin notes.

Comment: Maybe this: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/layout or try to find `layout` on CTAN http://www.ctan.org/search

Comment: @Sigur: I know the package, but I found it was maybe just too much for my current needs. I was looking for a more simple alternative.

Comment: @Marcos: Can you create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your current problem? If I create [a minimal example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ulORj.png) the [output `showframe` adjusts](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EoAy7.png) to the `\newgeometry`...

Comment: @Werner: Please, see my EDIT to the original question.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: @Jubobs: Please, see my last comment and the EDIT to my OP.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your request "It's not crop marks that I'm interested in, but the different layout areas, such as textblock, header and footer, and margin notes."

To see the different page measures, I consulted the "Normal Layout" image at ["Killmargins" package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158675/killmargins-package/158686#158686)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{This is also a header test}
\fancyfoot[C]{This is also a footer test}
\AddEverypageHook{\hbox{\color{blue!40}\smash{\hspace{\oddsidemargin}%
  \rule[-\textheight-\headsep-\headheight-\topmargin]{\textwidth}{\textheight}%
}}}
\AddEverypageHook{\hbox{\color{blue!30}\smash{\hspace{\oddsidemargin}%
  \rule[-\headheight-\topmargin]{\textwidth}{\headheight}%
}}}
\AddEverypageHook{\hbox{\color{blue!20}\smash{\hspace{\oddsidemargin}%
  \rule[-\textheight-\headsep-\headheight-\topmargin-\footskip]{\textwidth}{\headheight}%
}}}
\AddEverypageHook{\hbox{\color{blue!10}\smash{\hspace{\oddsidemargin}%
  \hspace{\textwidth}\hspace{\marginparsep}%
  \rule[-\textheight-\headsep-\headheight-\topmargin]{\marginparwidth}{\textheight}%
}}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\marginpar{this is a margin test}
\lipsum[2-7]
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDITED to present each text region as a different hook, and in a different color saturation.

REEDITED to account for the 2018.12.01 TeX kernel changes to `\smash`.

Answer (score 0):

A new page layout is shown by the `showframe` option of `geometry`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[4]
\newgeometry{rmargin=5cm}
\blindtext[4]
\restoregeometry
\blindtext[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, see my EDIT. I was confused about the actual origin of the problem. Should I open a new question?