# "Killmargins" package?

Tags: packages, margins

Editors such as "Gummi" show a split-screen with the LaTeX source code on the left, and a preview of the later document on the right. However, having a substantial paper margin makes editing more tedious due to the extra scrolling and the fact that the "Fit Page Width" scaling is not suitable when working with small screens.

For editing documents with a wide variety of document classes, which are often publisher-dependent, it would be nice to have a simple way of removing the page margin to 1 or 2 millimeters.

Is there some package for LaTeX that can read the current page layout settings and modify them accordingly, so that the publisher's layout stays the same? Of course, this could be done by defining the page geometry by hand, but this is relatively tedious as it would have to be done for every style file separately. In principle, shouldn't it be possible to have a package doing that for the user when being included?

Surely, the effect can be obtianed using "pdfcrop" or similar tools, but that slows down live preview considerably, not mentioning that some editors (such as "Gummi") do not support customizing the build command.

---

*Edit*: Here is an example for which tohecz's easy-to-use solution unfortunately does not work due to a "Package geometry Error: \paperheight (0.0pt) too short.":

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate} 
\usepackage[paperwidth=\dimexpr\the\textwidth+2em\relax, hmargin=1em]{geometry} 
\begin{document} 
Hello World 
\end{document}
```

Without the second line, the TeX code compiles file. The class file can be downloaded from http://acm.org/sigs/publications/sig-alternate.cls

Comment: I use `\addtolength{\hoffset}{-110pt}`

Comment: Very interesting question.  Actually, I think many pdf viewers would benefit from such an option, too.  (The only one I know is called... Kindle;).)

Comment: @mbork Goodreader on iPad handles cropping really well as well.

Comment: Maybe, I avoid anything with a bitten apple picture on it.  But to the point: another way might be to use Emacs instead of Gummi.  I am pretty sure that you could make a similar setup in Emacs in a moment (auto compiling+cropping+auto-reverting view - the last item exists already, the first one can be programmed in two minutes, the second one might need writing a shell script or a short elisp function.)  However, as noted in the question, performance might be bad (especially that pdf viewing in Emacs is based on converting the pdf to bitmaps). ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following, I do exactly the "tedious approach". I modify the physical page size and layout offsets (by altering `\pdfpagewidth`, `\pdfpageheight`, `\hoffset` and `\voffset`) without changing the publisher's layout itself.

While it is true that the actual numbers are highly class-specific, it is generally just two or three tries until one has found them.

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% tweak page size and offsets during development
% TODO: remove before submission
  \pdfpagewidth=7.2in
  \pdfpageheight=9.5in
  \hoffset=-0.65in
  \voffset=-0.65in
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{The Dark Side of The Moon: Legends, Myths, and Musik}

\author{Various Artitsts}
\maketitle              % typeset the title of the contribution

\begin{abstract}
The Dark Side of the Moon is the eighth studio album by the English progressive rock band Pink Floyd, released in March 1973. It built on ideas explored in the band's earlier recordings and live shows, but lacks the extended instrumental excursions that characterised their work following the departure in 1968 of founder member, principal composer, and lyricist, Syd Barrett. The Dark Side of the Moon's themes include conflict, greed, the passage of time, and mental illness, the latter partly inspired by Barrett's deteriorating mental state.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Will award the bounty in 2 days unless someone finds a "fully automatic" solution.

Comment: *There's no dark side of the moon really. Matter of fact, it's all dark.* -- Gotta love your answer and the reference to DSOTM! `:)`

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can add to your preamble the following line:

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=\dimexpr\the\textwidth+2em\relax, hmargin=1em]{geometry}
```

It will make a custom-sized page width, but preserve the set-up textwidth, and the page will have just very small horizontal margins. Similar tricks can be used for vertical margins, but it's more tricky because of headers and footers, so for that, one would actually need to know your exact settings.

Comment: Hmm. That does not seem to work for 2 columned layouts (the columns get a lot shorter. Also, at least with the "sig-alternate" style, this produces the error "Package geometry Error: \paperheight (0.0pt) too short." unless I set the paper height manually.

Comment: @Ruedi Well, compose a MWE then. Without a specific example, it's hard to know _that_ this doesn't work for you, or _why_ it is so.

Comment: Here is a M(N)WE: 

    \documentclass{sig-alternate}    \usepackage[paperwidth=\dimexpr\the\textwidth+2em\relax, hmargin=1em]{geometry}
    \begin{document}
    Hello World
    \end{document}  -- The class file can be downloaded from http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sig-alternate.cls

Comment: @Ruedi: Please add the MWE to your _question_, here in a comment it is unlikely found.

Comment: @Daniel: Good idea. Done.

Answer (score 4):

### `fullpage` package

You could be interested by the package `fullpage` which enlarges the text width.

Normal margins:

[image: normal margins]

With fullpage package declared:

[image: with fullpage]

Normal layout:

[image]

Fullpage layout:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{layout}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\layout
\end{document}
```

### `savetrees` package

There is also the `savetrees` package which is designed for using less paper when printing. This package reduces the margins like `fullpage` but go beyond that and  packs as much text as pos­si­ble onto each page. For example, the titles are in smaller fonts with less vertical space between them.

Here is an example:

[image]

MWE (by carefull, `savetrees` needs `lmodern` package).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{savetrees}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{layout}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\section{section 1}
\label{sec:section-1}

\subsection{subsection 1}
\label{sec:subsection-1}



\end{document}
```

Comment: But this actually changes the layout.

Comment: I should have probably stated explicitly that a requirement for the solution is that the layout is not changed, so that during editing of the document, formulas can be split into parts so that they fit the final layout, figures can be designed that way, etc.

Comment: Ok, sorry I missed this point.

Answer (score 2):

A "fully automatic" solution is difficult, a document might use headers, footers, marginal stuff, ...

Therefore the example uses the layout conventions of the used class `sig-alternate`:

```
\documentclass[preprint]{sig-alternate}

\newif\ifkillmargins
\killmarginstrue % configure

\ifkillmargins
  % horizontal settings
  % -------------------
  \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1mm}% configure
  \setlength{\paperwidth}{\textwidth}
  \addtolength{\paperwidth}{2\oddsidemargin}
  % the class sig-alternate forbids marginal paragraphs
  \addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1in}% TeX origin fix
  \setlength{\evensidemargin}{\oddsidemargin}

  \setlength{\topmargin}{1mm}%
  \setlength{\paperheight}{\textheight}
  \addtolength{\paperheight}{2\topmargin}
  % class sig-alternate forbids page headings
  \addtolength{\topmargin}{-\headheight}
  \addtolength{\topmargin}{-\headsep}
  % class sig-alternate does not seem to use a footer (\let\thepage\relax)
  % \addtolength{\paperheight}{\footskip}
  \addtolength{\paperheight}{\maxdepth}
  \addtolength{\topmargin}{-1in}% TeX origin fix

  % propagate settings of paper size to the driver
  % without changing the layout
  \usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\fi

\begin{document}
  \Large
  \noindent
  Top left\leaders\hbox{$\cdot$}\hfill top right\par
  \vfill\centerline{\huge\bfseries column 1}\vfill
  \noindent
  left\footnote{bottom left\leaders\hbox{$\cdot$}\hfill bottom right}%
  \hfill right
  \newpage
  \noindent
  Top left\leaders\hbox{$\cdot$}\hfill top right\par
  \vfill\centerline{\huge\bfseries column 2}\vfill
  \noindent
  bottom left\leaders\hbox{$\cdot$}\hfill bottom right%
  \newpage
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]