# Coloring only the text area

Tags: color, geometry

I use the geometry package to define paper size and text area of a (one page) document:

```
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=420mm,
  paperheight=297mm,
  text={365mm,270mm},
  centering
]{geometry}
```

I wish to color the background of the specified text area. I use this.

```
\usepackage{color}
\pagecolor{magenta}
```

This, however, colors the whole paper (420*297 mm2), rather than just the text area (365*270 mm2).

How do I color *only* the text area?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`tikzpagenodes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand\ColorTextArea{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[cyan!20] 
  (current page text area.north west) rectangle (current page text area.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\ColorTextArea
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `showframe` package was only used to have some frames for the page layout to help visualization.

`\ColorTextArea` only affects the page in which it was invoked. If you want the effect for all the pages, use the `atbegshi` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand\ColorTextArea{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[cyan!20] 
  (current page text area.north west) rectangle (current page text area.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\AtBeginShipout{\ColorTextArea}
\AtBeginShipoutFirst{\ColorTextArea}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

This way it is automatically done every page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\AddEverypageHook{\color{blue!20}\smash{\hspace{\oddsidemargin}%
  \rule[-\textheight-\headsep-\headheight-\topmargin]{\textwidth}{\textheight}}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{document}
```

Thanks to ["Killmargins" package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158675/killmargins-package/158686#comment364626_158686) for the images of text measures.

[image]