# How to determine page size and orientation

Tags: paper-size

I try make a macro that has to work differently depending upon page size and orientation.

What are the commands to determine page size (a4, a5, a6) and orientation (portrait or lanscape) ?

Comment: Off course ! Thank's. Please, write an answer.

Comment: There are various Q&A's on the site that show the image of the LaTeX page layout, such as here:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158675/killmargins-package/158686#158686.  Those images tell what LaTeX length corresponds to what page dimension.

Comment: I knew all this, my question was "give me directly paper size as a4, a5, a6, letter ... without any calculation" ;-). Thank you.

Comment: "Without any calculation??!!"  Next thing you'll be wanting a backslash character in OT1 encoding `8^b`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use `\paperwidth`&`\paperheight`, `\pdfpagewidth`&`\pdfpageheight` (sometimes I use `\maxdimen`, if needed) and `\ifdim`...`\else`...`\fi` when I need to set up something depending on these dimensions.

There is one fine example, please see http://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html#ifdim-rp