# Showing margins/frames in beamer slides

Tags: beamer, geometry

With a regular article/report/... class, you can use the `showframe` package to draw outlines of where the various regions of the page lie.  I cannot get the same functionality with `beamer`, however.  Using `geometry` with its `showframe` option similarly does not work.

How can I get this functionality with `beamer`?

### MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}  % Doesn't work
\usepackage{showframe}             % Doesn't work

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Slide Title}
\centering
Centered Text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

#### Edit:

A similar question is posed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96201/is-there-an-overview-of-beamers-slide-page-geometry-anywhere) that asks for a diagram depicting the layout of the page with lengths of various parameters given.  The `\layout` package gives this output when applied to the MWE:

[image: layout]

While this output gives margin information and general layout information, it does not give the visual output that I am looking for, with boxes overlaid on my own content.
I am less interested in seeing the value of margins and other lengths than I am in visualizing the fit of my own content on the slide and seeing how close the boxes actually are to content.  This is why I desire functionality more close to what the `showframe` package would provide.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [How does `beamer` build the `frame`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26299/5764)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I applied  to `beamer` the answer at [Displaying layout marks in a document set with different layouts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156976/displaying-layout-marks-in-a-document-set-with-different-layouts/160360#160360), which gives some of the information you seek.  It shades the main text block, that margin block, the header block, and the footer block.

However, the beamer frame sits atop the underlying page dimensions, and so things like the frame title are not captured by the normal page text blocks.  Further, things like `\marginpar`s can be done in `beamer`, but not inside a `frame`.  Lastly, there are some page dimensions such as `\textheight` which could not be set in the preamble without being immediately overwritten.  Interestingly, I discovered that when not in a `frame`, `beamer` will page break and move residual text to the next page (something it does not do inside a `frame`).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% In beamer, these changes can be made in the preamble
\addtolength{\topmargin}{1pt}
\addtolength{\headsep}{5pt}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-4pt}
\addtolength{\marginparwidth}{20pt}
\addtolength{\marginparsep}{-3pt}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-5pt}
%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{This is also a header test}
\fancyfoot[C]{This is also a footer test}
\AddEverypageHook{\hbox{\color{blue!40}\smash{\hspace{\oddsidemargin}%
  \rule[-\textheight-\headsep-\headheight-\topmargin]{\textwidth}{\textheight}%
}}}
\AddEverypageHook{\hbox{\color{blue!30}\smash{\hspace{\oddsidemargin}%
  \rule[-\headheight-\topmargin]{\textwidth}{\headheight}%
}}}
\AddEverypageHook{\hbox{\color{blue!20}\smash{\hspace{\oddsidemargin}%
  \rule[-\textheight-\headsep-\headheight-\topmargin-\footskip]{\textwidth}{\headheight}%
}}}
\AddEverypageHook{\hbox{\color{blue!10}\smash{\hspace{\oddsidemargin}%
  \hspace{\textwidth}\hspace{\marginparsep}%
  \rule[-\textheight-\headsep-\headheight-\topmargin]{\marginparwidth}{\textheight}%
}}}
\begin{document}
% In beamer, these changes have no effect in preamble
\addtolength{\textheight}{-40pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{15pt}
\addtolength{\footskip}{15pt}
%
\begin{frame}{title of the slide}
\lipsum[3]
\end{frame}
\clearpage
\lipsum[3]\marginpar{this is a margin test}

\end{document}
```

This is a slide within a frame:

[image]

This is the next slide, not in a frame:

[image]

EDITED to account for the 2018.12.01 TeX kernel changes to `\smash`.

Comment: This is nice, and I think it adequately shows the different spaces, though not in quite the same way as `showframes`.  I'll accept it for now unless anything better comes along.

Comment: where the heck is that text with the "Nulla malesuda.." comming from, how can i get rid off that ?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ That is the `lipsum` package and anything that says `\lipsum` is producing that text.