# Is there a way to indicate the different area elements prescribed by the geometry package?

Tags: positioning, geometry

The `geometry` package prescribes areas such as header, footer, textarea, marginpar, etc. by using length variables such as `tmargin`, `bmargin`, `headsep`, etc.

When you do "Inspect Element" in your browser, hover over an HTML line, an HTML element is highlighted, visually indicating margins, padding, etc.

Is there a way to do the same thing in LaTeX?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156976/displaying-layout-marks-in-a-document-set-with-different-layouts

Comment: There's the `layout` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option using the [`layout`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/layout) package to get a diagram showing the relevant parts and their dimensions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,hmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{layout}
\begin{document}
\layout
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, anothe approach using [`tikzpagenodes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes) to get a visual demarcation of the relevant areas:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[blue,line width=2mm]
  (current page.south west)
  rectangle
  (current page.north east);
\draw[green]
  (current page text area.south west)
  rectangle
  (current page text area.north east);
\draw[yellow]
  (current page marginpar area.south west)
  rectangle
  (current page marginpar area.north east);
\draw[red]
  (current page header area.south west)
  rectangle
  (current page header area.north east);
\draw[orange]
  (current page footer area.south west)
  rectangle
  (current page footer area.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another possibility is to use the [`layouts`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/layouts) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[marginparwidth=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{layouts}

\begin{document}

\currentpage
\oddpagelayouttrue
\pagedesign

\end{document}
```

[image]